# How to achieve auto contextual linking in the Umbraco CMS?

Tags: seo, umbraco, umbraco6, internal-link

I want to manage internal contextual link building in my articles, but somewhat in a well-managed and easier way. It is a pain to change all the link [URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator) in a text if we change a URL of a page which is linked to many pages in their content.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to change them if you used the content picker to select the page you are linking to because it inserts a URL in the format `{localLink:####}` where `###` is the id of the document the link is pointing to.

This is then parsed and replaced with the correct and current URL when the document is rendered, so it is always current and correct.